Plotutils / Plotfont: get specific character (HPGL) code

GNU plotfont is a simple utility that will produce a character map for any font available to the GNU plotting utilities graph, plot, pic2plot, and tek2plot, and the GNU libplot graphics library on which they are based.

https://www.gnu.org/software/plotutils/manual/en/html_node/plotfont-Examples.html#plotfont-Examples
example:
plotfont -T hpgl HersheySans

Will produce a character map of the HersheySans in HPGL code.
The code contains all the characters and they don't seem to be separated or independant from each other. How do I get only a specific character HPGL code with plotfont? Is there an other tool that would allow me to do this?

If you have plotfont you may have pic2plot which allows you to convert
a minimal pic format picture into one of the many plot formats. For
example, for the character x:
printf '.PS\n "x" \n.PE\n' | 
pic2plot -FHersheySans --font-size .5 -Thpgl

will produce something like (output split for readabilit)
BP;IN;PS10668;IP0,0,8128,8128;SC0,10000,0,10000;WU1;SP1;TR0;LT;
LA1,4,2,4;LA3,10;PW1.5214;
PA4167,5758;PM0;PD;PA5833,3636;PU;PM2;EP;
PA5833,5758;PM0;PD;PA4167,3636;PU;PM2;EP;
PA0,0;SP0;PG0;

The 2 lines beginning PA Plot Absolute are the instructions to stroke
each bar of the x character.
